# I have an application created in reactjs. I want to add this in the existing WordPress site. I have tried using reactpres plugin bhut didn't worked

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, plugins

I have created multiple calculators related to finance using reactjs in the localhost. Now I want to add these calculators in the existing WordPress site. I tried searching for the solution but found nothing till now.

I tried using reactpres plugin which is there to add reactjs in WordPress. But for some reason when I copy the build folder in the app inside reactpres it throws error.